# How to catch specific error in fbx export

Tags: python

How can I try, except for only:

RuntimeError: Error: Tangent space can only be computed for tris/quads, aborting

and also store the message (Tangent space can only be computed for tris/quads, aborting)

```
try:
    export_fbx_tangent_on(self, context, save_dir)
except RuntimeError as e:
    message = f'w:Fbx export failed,{e}'
```

Comment: I also have this error trying to get tangents from a mesh with custom normals when I use the calc_tangents() function. It seems that the mesh must be tris or quads, so perhaps try triangulating the mesh before exporting?

Comment: Yeah I know why I get the error, I just want to catch the error.